# how to change one value from Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 columns in my dataframe, one called 'Subreddits' which lists string values, and one called 'Appearances' which lists how many times they appear. 
I am trying to add 1 to the value of a certain line in the 'Appearances' column when it detects a string value that is already in the dataframe.

```
 df = pd.read_csv(Location)


print(len(elem))

while counter < 50:

    #gets just the subreddit name
    e = str(elem[counter].get_attribute("href"))
    e = e.replace("https://www.reddit.com/r/", "")
    e = e[:-1]

    inDf = None

    if (any(df.Subreddit == e)):
        print("Y")
        inDf = True

    if inDf:
        #adds 1 to the value of Appearances
        #df.set_value(e, 'Appearances', 2, takeable=False)
        #df.at[e, 'Appearances'] +=1
    else:
        #adds new row with the subreddit name and sets the amount of appearances to 1.
        df = df.append({'Subreddit': e, 'Appearances': 1}, ignore_index=True)




    print(e)
    counter = counter + 2

print(df)
```

The only part that is giving me trouble is the  `if inDF` section. I cannot figure out how to add 1 to the 'Appearances' of the subreddit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is a bit messy here, you don't need 3 references to `inDF`, or need to instantiate it with `None`, or use built-in `any` with a `pd.Series` object.

You can check whether the value exists in a series via the `in` operator:

```
if e in df['Subreddit'].values:
    df.loc[df['Subreddit'] == e, 'Appearances'] += 1
else:
    df = df.append({'Subreddit': e, 'Appearances': 1}, ignore_index=True)
```

Even better, use a `defaultdict` in your loop and create your dataframe at the very end of the process. Your current use of `pd.DataFrame.append` is not recommended as the expensive operation is being repeated for each row.

```
from collections import defaultdict

#initialise dictionary
dd = defaultdict(int)

while counter < 50:
    e = ...                  # gets just the subreddit name
    dd[e] += 1               # increment count by 1
    counter = counter + 2    # increment while loop counter

# create results dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dd, orient='index').reset_index()

# rename columns
df.columns = ['Subreddit', 'Appearances']
```

Comment: thank you for the help. I would like to eventually make the program quicker, but for now I am just trying to get used to things. I am having one other problem now, where a column called "unnamed" appears every time I run it. I have tried to fix it with no success. any idea why it is appearing?

Comment: @jackarnold, Possibly your CSV file has an unnamed column. But hard to tell, you should search for other Q&A on this issue, or ask a new question with a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.loc[df['Subreddits'] == e, 'Appearances'] += 1`

example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Subreddits', 'Appearances'])
e_list = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c']
for e in e_list:
    inDF = (df['Subreddits'] == e).sum() > 0
    if inDF:
        df.loc[df['Subreddits'] == e, 'Appearances'] += 1
    else:
        df = df.append([{'Subreddits': e, 'Appearances': 1}])
df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True) # good idea to reset the index..
print(df)

  Subreddits Appearances
0          a           3
1          b           2
2          c           1
```